# Complex integration of a function around a triangle.

Tags: complex-integration

Please help me how to solve this problem. I have no idea how to initiate the solution. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\gamma_1: z = t\\
\gamma_2: z = a + ti\\
\gamma_3: z = a - t + (a-t)i$

Take the derivatives to find $dz$ for each contour

$\int_0^a t \ dt + \int_0^a a (i \ dt) + \int_0^a (a-t)(-1-i\ dt)$

Comment: By your hint , I got 2nd option. But what is a rule by which you constructed the functions?

Comment: You need a parametric equation for a line that gets you from point to point.  If you want to get from $x_0 + iy_0 $ to $x_1+iy_1$ then $z = (x_1-x_0) t + x_0  + ((y_1 - y_0)t + y_0)i$ will get you between those two points.

Comment: Is this a general rule for finding parametric equation from one point to another point? I read the result: Let A and B be two extreme points of a curve then Z(t)= A(1-t)+Bt if 0<t<1 . But in above problem, there is no such condition on it.